# Jquery Slider Displaying Blank Slide

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm working on http://lobounce.com.s138810.gridserver.com/ and have been having some problems with the slider which uses SlidesJS. For some reason, it displays a blank slide which it shouldn't. I checked and it looks like a list element is being added to the pagination class, but I can't tell why.

Here is Slider.php

```
<div id="slides">
    <ul class="slides_container">
        <?php $query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => '4','post_type' => 'featured'));
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
            $video_source = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_meta_box_source', true);
            $video_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_meta_box_videoid', true);
            if(($video_source == "vimeo") && !empty($video_id)){ ?>
                <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $video_id; ?>?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=e275c7" width="822" height="292" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
            <?php } elseif(( $video_source == "youtube") && !empty($video_id)){ ?>
                <iframe width="822" height="292" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $video_id; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <?php  }
            $target_link =  get_permalink();
            $post_behaviour = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slider_meta_box_behaviour', true);  
            if ($post_behaviour == 'external_link')
            {
                $target_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slider_meta_box_target_link', true);
            } 
            else if ($post_behaviour == 'no_link')
            {
                $target_link = false;
            }

            if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
            ?>
            <li>
            <?php
                if($target_link)
            {
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $target_link; ?>">
                    <?php gorilla_img('slider');?>
                </a>
            <?php 
            } else { 
            ?>  
                <?php gorilla_img('slider');?>
            <?php 
                } 
            ?>
            </li>
            <?php
            } else{ ?> 
            <li>
            <?php
                if($target_link)
            {
                ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $target_link; ?>">
            <?php gorilla_img('slider');?>
            </a>
            <?php 
            } else { 
            ?>  
                <?php gorilla_img('slider');?>
            <?php 
                } 
            ?>
            </li>
            <?php } endwhile; endif;?>
    </ul>
</div><!-- slider closed -->
```

slides.min.jquery.js:

```
/*
* Slides, A Slideshow Plugin for jQuery
* Intructions: http://slidesjs.com
* By: Nathan Searles, http://nathansearles.com
* Version: 1.1.9
* Updated: September 5th, 2011
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/
(function(a){a.fn.slides=function(b){return b=a.extend({},a.fn.slides.option,b),this.each(function(){function w(g,h,i){if(!p&&o){p=!0,b.animationStart(n+1);switch(g){case"next":l=n,k=n+1,k=e===k?0:k,r=f*2,g=-f*2,n=k;break;case"prev":l=n,k=n-1,k=k===-1?e-1:k,r=0,g=0,n=k;break;case"pagination":k=parseInt(i,10),l=a("."+b.paginationClass+" li."+b.currentClass+" a",c).attr("href").match("[^#/]+$"),k>l?(r=f*2,g=-f*2):(r=0,g=0),n=k}h==="fade"?b.crossfade?d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).css({zIndex:10}).fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing,function(){b.autoHeight?d.animate({height:d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).outerHeight()},b.autoHeightSpeed,function(){d.children(":eq("+l+")",c).css({display:"none",zIndex:0}),d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).css({zIndex:0}),b.animationComplete(k+1),p=!1}):(d.children(":eq("+l+")",c).css({display:"none",zIndex:0}),d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).css({zIndex:0}),b.animationComplete(k+1),p=!1)}):d.children(":eq("+l+")",c).fadeOut(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing,function(){b.autoHeight?d.animate({height:d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).outerHeight()},b.autoHeightSpeed,function(){d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing)}):d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing,function(){a.browser.msie&&a(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter")}),b.animationComplete(k+1),p=!1}):(d.children(":eq("+k+")").css({left:r,display:"block"}),b.autoHeight?d.animate({left:g,height:d.children(":eq("+k+")").outerHeight()},b.slideSpeed,b.slideEasing,function(){d.css({left:-f}),d.children(":eq("+k+")").css({left:f,zIndex:5}),d.children(":eq("+l+")").css({left:f,display:"none",zIndex:0}),b.animationComplete(k+1),p=!1}):d.animate({left:g},b.slideSpeed,b.slideEasing,function(){d.css({left:-f}),d.children(":eq("+k+")").css({left:f,zIndex:5}),d.children(":eq("+l+")").css({left:f,display:"none",zIndex:0}),b.animationComplete(k+1),p=!1})),b.pagination&&(a("."+b.paginationClass+" li."+b.currentClass,c).removeClass(b.currentClass),a("."+b.paginationClass+" li:eq("+k+")",c).addClass(b.currentClass))}}function x(){clearInterval(c.data("interval"))}function y(){b.pause?(clearTimeout(c.data("pause")),clearInterval(c.data("interval")),u=setTimeout(function(){clearTimeout(c.data("pause")),v=setInterval(function(){w("next",i)},b.play),c.data("interval",v)},b.pause),c.data("pause",u)):x()}a("."+b.container,a(this)).children().wrapAll('<div class="slides_control"/>');var c=a(this),d=a(".slides_control",c),e=d.children().size(),f=d.children().outerWidth(),g=d.children().outerHeight(),h=b.start-1,i=b.effect.indexOf(",")<0?b.effect:b.effect.replace(" ","").split(",")[0],j=b.effect.indexOf(",")<0?i:b.effect.replace(" ","").split(",")[1],k=0,l=0,m=0,n=0,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v;if(e<2)return a("."+b.container,a(this)).fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing,function(){o=!0,b.slidesLoaded()}),a("."+b.next+", ."+b.prev).fadeOut(0),!1;if(e<2)return;h<0&&(h=0),h>e&&(h=e-1),b.start&&(n=h),b.randomize&&d.randomize(),a("."+b.container,c).css({overflow:"hidden",position:"relative"}),d.children().css({position:"absolute",top:0,left:d.children().outerWidth(),zIndex:0,display:"none"}),d.css({position:"relative",width:f*3,height:g,left:-f}),a("."+b.container,c).css({display:"block"}),b.autoHeight&&(d.children().css({height:"auto"}),d.animate({height:d.children(":eq("+h+")").outerHeight()},b.autoHeightSpeed));if(b.preload&&d.find("img:eq("+h+")").length){a("."+b.container,c).css({background:"url("+b.preloadImage+") no-repeat 50% 50%"});var z=d.find("img:eq("+h+")").attr("src")+"?"+(new Date).getTime();a("img",c).parent().attr("class")!="slides_control"?t=d.children(":eq(0)")[0].tagName.toLowerCase():t=d.find("img:eq("+h+")"),d.find("img:eq("+h+")").attr("src",z).load(function(){d.find(t+":eq("+h+")").fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing,function(){a(this).css({zIndex:5}),a("."+b.container,c).css({background:""}),o=!0,b.slidesLoaded()})})}else d.children(":eq("+h+")").fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing,function(){o=!0,b.slidesLoaded()});b.bigTarget&&(d.children().css({cursor:"pointer"}),d.children().click(function(){return w("next",i),!1})),b.hoverPause&&b.play&&(d.bind("mouseover",function(){x()}),d.bind("mouseleave",function(){y()})),b.generateNextPrev&&(a("."+b.container,c).after('<a href="#" class="'+b.prev+'">Prev</a>'),a("."+b.prev,c).after('<a href="#" class="'+b.next+'">Next</a>')),a("."+b.next,c).click(function(a){a.preventDefault(),b.play&&y(),w("next",i)}),a("."+b.prev,c).click(function(a){a.preventDefault(),b.play&&y(),w("prev",i)}),b.generatePagination?(b.prependPagination?c.prepend("<ul class="+b.paginationClass+"></ul>"):c.append("<ul class="+b.paginationClass+"></ul>"),d.children().each(function(){a("."+b.paginationClass,c).append('<li><a href="#'+m+'">'+(m+1)+"</a></li>"),m++})):a("."+b.paginationClass+" li a",c).each(function(){a(this).attr("href","#"+m),m++}),a("."+b.paginationClass+" li:eq("+h+")",c).addClass(b.currentClass),a("."+b.paginationClass+" li a",c).click(function(){return b.play&&y(),q=a(this).attr("href").match("[^#/]+$"),n!=q&&w("pagination",j,q),!1}),a("a.link",c).click(function(){return b.play&&y(),q=a(this).attr("href").match("[^#/]+$")-1,n!=q&&w("pagination",j,q),!1}),b.play&&(v=setInterval(function(){w("next",i)},b.play),c.data("interval",v))})},a.fn.slides.option={preload:!1,preloadImage:"/img/loading.gif",container:"slides_container",generateNextPrev:!1,next:"next",prev:"prev",pagination:!0,generatePagination:!0,prependPagination:!1,paginationClass:"pagination",currentClass:"current",fadeSpeed:350,fadeEasing:"",slideSpeed:350,slideEasing:"",start:1,effect:"slide",crossfade:!1,randomize:!1,play:0,pause:0,hoverPause:!1,autoHeight:!1,autoHeightSpeed:350,bigTarget:!1,animationStart:function(){},animationComplete:function(){},slidesLoaded:function(){}},a.fn.randomize=function(b){function c(){return Math.round(Math.random())-.5}return a(this).each(function(){var d=a(this),e=d.children(),f=e.length;if(f>1){e.hide();var g=[];for(i=0;i<f;i++)g[g.length]=i;g=g.sort(c),a.each(g,function(a,c){var f=e.eq(c),g=f.clone(!0);g.show().appendTo(d),b!==undefined&&b(f,g),f.remove()})}})}})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell enough to know if this is your problem, but even if it isn't, it'll cause other problems eventually:

In your page you load a file http://lobounce.com.s138810.gridserver.com/wp-content/themes/DanceFloorV2/js/jquery.cycle.all.js.js that doesn't exist (notice the .js.js at the end, I tried it with just one .js and the file was then found, looks like a simple typo).

I'd assume that missing .js file then leads to the next error I see about your script trying to call a method "cycle" that doesn't exist (because the file with the method isn't loaded). However, we won't know if that's actually the problem until you fix it, so can't tell you for sure.